# TextView alignment broken after TextSize changed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There's just so many questions regarding a similar problem that I can't find anything that would help me fix something specific.
I have a TextView inside a FrameLayout and since there is no auto-scaling, I calculate the text size using Paint and getTextBounds. The size seems to be ok, but the alignment gets broken after I change the TextSize - the text gets a strange margin from the top.

1. Yes, I do use ViewTreeObserver to apply the change only after the layout is drawn.
2. Setting gravity to Top and Left still leaves the text shifted down a bit.

Here's the code for the layout, nothing special about it:

```
<FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/labelCreditsFrame"
 android:baselineAligned="false"           
 android:layout_weight="3">
 <TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="1000"
  android:id="@+id/labelCredits"
  android:typeface="sans"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:phoneNumber="false"
  android:autoText="false"
  android:textColor="#ff000000"
  android:ellipsize="start" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And here's the code that's being run after the layout loads - which seemingly gets the right size for the text so that it fills its parent layout. It just paints the text, measures it and then checks if it still fits inside the FrameLayout.

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.labelCreditsFrame);
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.labelCredits);
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
Rect result = new Rect();
final float density = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
textPaint.set(text.getPaint());
float testSize = 5;
boolean test = true;
while(test){
 textPaint.setTextSize(testSize+2);
 textPaint.getTextBounds(text.getText().toString(), 0, text.getText().toString().length(), result);
 test = (result.width()*density<frame.getMeasuredWidth() && result.height()*density<frame.getMeasuredHeight());
 if(test) testSize += 2;
}
text.setTextSize(testSize);
```

The resulting text is, as said above, shifted down and it's even partially outside the FrameLayout, so a piece of it gets cut off. I just can't figure out where the problem is or what else could I try, since Android development is sometimes really unclear.

Any help or hints would be really appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Edit: Here's the structure of the whole activity. Everything else is just plain frames with their weights and no other code is being run. The highlighted FrameLayout is the layout holding the TextView and the one that is used for deciding if the tested text size still fits. The TextView itself has both its width and height set to wrap_content.

[image: Structure]

And here's a quick photo (sorry for the bad quality) of the result:

[image]

Comment: but why you are use only textview ??use one Linear or Relative layout and inside this layout use textview.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question right - but this is just a part of the whole layout. There are more layouts and elements on the screen, but I posted just this part to make it legible. Also the TextView isn't there by itself, it's inside a FrameLayout.

Comment: not understand please add your content in question

Comment: Added a screenshot of the whole structure. The XML source is pretty long and as I say above, all the other elements are just placeholders. The only XML that matters is the one in the question.

Comment: why you are using frame layout ?? see what you did here you have user one linear layout inside it you have used one another Linear Layout and frame Layout No need to do that just use direct Textview so you can set Other properties